# actualizar datos en dos tablas mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy tratando de actualizar datos de un tabla que se encuentra almacenada en una base de datos, pero al realizarlo necesito que cambie el dato en otra tabla este es mi codigo:

```
$sql="update Mprima,detalle_Dproducto 
                set Mprima.precio=detalle_Dproducto.precio

                  materiales=?,
                  unidadm=?,
                  moneda=?,
                  precio=?,
                  stock=?,
                  estado=?,
                  id_usuario=?
                  where 
                  detalle_Dproducto.id_detalle_Dproducto=Mprima.id_Mprima

                ";
                  
                 //echo $sql; exit();

                   $sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);

                    $sql->bindValue(1,$_POST["materiales"]);
                    $sql->bindValue(2,$_POST["unidadm"]);
                    $sql->bindValue(3, $_POST["moneda"]);
                    $sql->bindValue(4,$_POST["precio"]);
                    $sql->bindValue(5, $stocker);
                    $sql->bindValue(6,$_POST["estado"]);
                    $sql->bindValue(7,$_POST["id_usuario"]);
                    
                    $sql->execute();
```

Comment: Estas tratando de hacer un update a dos tablas al mismo tiempo en la misma query????

Comment: si, quiero que al actualizar una, cambie tambien la otra que tiene en este caso la variable precio

Comment: Por favor, no cambies tu pregunta, si no la respuesta queda obsoleta...

Comment: las disculpas de el caso

Comment: vamos a tratar de entender porque no anda tu query. Lo probaste directamente en la db? hace lo que tiene que hacer? los datos que te llegan estan bien? ojo porque lo que no te asegura un query asi, es el orden en que va actualizar tus campos.

Comment: desde php por medio de un formulario estoy tratando de hacer el update

Comment: si eso se ve en tu codigo. Lo que pregunto es si esa query funciona en la db. Si los datos llegan bien. si el orden de actualizacion es correcto...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el lenguaje SQL la sentencia `update` está concebida para actualizar fila(s) de **una** tabla, y solo una.

Por tanto, no tienes de otra que preparar y lanzar dos sentencias `update` consecutivas, una para cada tabla, por ejemplo:

```
$sqlMprima = "
update Mprima
   set precio = ?
 where alguna_condicion   
";

$sqlDetalle = "
update detalle_Dproducto
   set materiales = ?,
      unidadm = ?,
      moneda = ?,
      precio = ?,
      stock = ?,
      estado = ?,
      id_usuario = ?
 where alguna_condicion
";

$qMprima = $conectar->prepare($sqlMprima);
$qDetalle = $conectar->prepare($sqlDetalle);

$qMprima->bindValue(1, $_POST["precio"]);
$qDetalle->bindValue(1, $_POST["materiales"]);
$qDetalle->bindValue(2, $_POST["unidadm"]);
$qDetalle->bindValue(3, $_POST["moneda"]);
$qDetalle->bindValue(4, $_POST["precio"]);
$qDetalle->bindValue(5, $stocker);
$qDetalle->bindValue(6, $_POST["estado"]);
$qDetalle->bindValue(7, $_POST["id_usuario"]);

$qMprima->execute();
$qDetalle->execute();
```

Es común que un sistema actualice información de varias tablas en el contexto de una [transacción ACID](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), de manera que si algo falla, se pueda echar para atrás lo que ya se ha actualizado antes, si ese fuese tu caso, puedes valerte de los métodos [`begin_transaction()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php), [`commit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php) y [`rollback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.rollback.php) para tirar de la *acidez* de la base de datos.

Comment: gracias por tu conocimiento, tratare de adaptarlo.

Comment: creo que seria de esta manera pero de igual manera no hace la funcionalidad, no se cual seria el problema

Comment: en realidad, en mysql si se puede hacer... pero para mi gusto, es una barbaridad...

Comment: @wilbertpalacios que quiere decir que no lo hace? tira un error? directamente no actualiza nada? los parametros estan bien? las querys funcionan por separado?

Comment: no actualiza nada

Comment: solamente me actualiza Mprima pero no realiza el cambio en la otra tabla

Comment: revisa la cláusula `where` de tu sentencia, si no actualiza nada, probablemente hay algún _detalle_ allí. La otra es lanzar la sentencia manualmente contra el motor, por ejemplo con phpMyAdmin, ¿Allí funciona?

Comment: ok gracias revisare el where, ya que al ahora que hago el update me da el error que el id_detalle_Dproducto no esta definido, que seria el id de la segunda tabla